# Connection to Domino Notes Databse using COM failed on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, lotus-domino

I have created one application using MVC5 to connect to Notes database using COM interop domino dll. It works fine on my local but doesn't works through IIS of my computer. It gives login view but failed to connect to database and gives an

> An error occurred while processing your request.

So I think there is a database connectivity problem with notes database. Is there any difference between accessing database using local and IIS? I haven't changed anything for IIS, just configure it to run the mvc application.
I am using 64bit OS.

Any idea why I can't connect to notes database using IIS?

Comment: What do you mean "It gives login view?"  Please show your code and identify what line fails and what the acutal error code or message is. Also, please note that IBM does not officially support the Domino COM classes on 64 bits. It is known that it can be made to work for most ordinary operations. I.e., working with specific documents and views works, but the methods that deal with design element collections (e.g., getting all the views in a database) are broken. If there are other problems, it is unlikely that IBM will help with them.

Comment: Here is IBM's statement about lack of support: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291

Comment: well, now i can connect to db:  var ns = new NotesSessionClass();
                ns.Initialize("Password");
                NotesDatabase db = ns.GetDatabase("DominoServer"], "Database", false);        but when i tried to save new document, it gives an error like: unauthorized user. permission failed.my code is : if (doc.ComputeWithForm(true, true))
                {
                    doc.ReplaceItemValue("EmployeeID", employee.Id);
                    doc.Save(false, false);
                }   I set all permission in ACL list.

Comment: Inability to save documents, after connecting, is usually a user-rights issue. Make sure the user-ID has appropriate rights to access the server, access the database (acl), and create docs (acl) and/or see/update docs (readers/author fields, field encryption, access-controlled sections and acl).